# Javascript interface Callback not working in android webview API >= 21 with GWT 2.7 javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, gwt, android-webview

I am facing a particular problem with my code. The javascript callbacks are working on devices with api level 19 or lower but it is **not working on API 21 and above**. Strangely normal Html javascript callback is working on all API levels. I'm not using proguard. Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
WebAppInterface wai = new WebAppInterface(this, this);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(wai, "Android");
myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.2.246/abhishek/test/");
```

WebAppInterface.java

```
class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    MainActivity parent;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c, MainActivity parent) {
        mContext = c;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setHeading(String heading) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Setting heading to " + heading, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

GWT code:

javascript:

```
function setHeading(heading) {
    console.log("setting heading...");
    // Android callback
    if(typeof Android !== 'undefined'){ 
        Android.setHeading(heading);
    }
    if(typeof Android == 'undefined') {
        console.log("undefined!!");
    }
}
```

java:

```
public static final native void setAppHeading(String heading) /*-{
    $wnd.setHeading(heading);
}-*/;
```

I am getting typeof Android as 'undefined' on lollipop and above. Can anyone give tell me what's wrong in this or give me a sample code with GWT javascript that works on Android API level 21 and above.

Comment: Maybe a race condition? You might want to put it in a Timer just to make sure it is not.

Comment: I tried adding setTimeout(function () {$wnd.setHeading(heading);}, 3000); and it worked!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout delay seems to solve the issue. I don't know how but it works.

```
public static final native void setAppHeading(String heading) /*-{
    setTimeout(function() {$wnd.setHeading(heading);}, 3000);
}-*/;
```

Turns out the callback object was attached at the window level and javascript code was executed in the inner iFrame created by GWT.

```
public static final native void setAppHeading(String heading) /*-{
    if(typeof $wnd.Android !== 'undefined'){ 
        $wnd.Android.setHeading(heading);
        return;
    }
}-*/;
```

So this code works.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a race condition? You might want to put it in a Timer just to make sure it is not.

**UPDATE**:

Since it was indeed a race condition, setting the timer to 1ms might suffice and using the following might be best practice:

```
Scheduler.scheduleDeferred
```

See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html